# Passing a Bundle with a Parcelable object from Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, jython, android-intent, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to pass a Parcelable object in my extras when starting an activity in Monkeyrunner.  The area in the script looks like this

```
user = FbUser() 
extraDic = {} 
extraDic['userName'] = 'Test' 
extraDic['userId'] = 'me' 
extraDic['userInfo'] = user 
d.startActivity(extras=extraDic, component=runComponent + postActivity)
```

FbUser is the object in my java project that implements Parcelable. The bin of the project has been properly added to the sys.path in the Jython Monkeyrunner script.  When I debug the script, it creates the FbUser object correctly, however, when I print out the extras in LogCat, the 'userInfo' extra is missing...  This appears to be because the class JythonUtils will only translate PyString, PyFloat and PyInteger to String, Double and Integer even though the documentation for MonkeyDevice states you can pass *any* structured data type in the extras dictionary.  Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've come into that problem just recently and read the source to find out that unfortunately this is not possible.

MonkeyDevice instance delegates its work to [am command by adb -](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-sdk/com/android/monkeyrunner/adb/AdbMonkeyDevice.java.htm). As you may already know, the extras that am is able to accept from command line is [quite limited](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/cmds/am/src/com/android/commands/am/Am.java.shtml). In fact it can carry a String, a boolean or an int.